# Is there any evidence that some people who claim to see auras around persons actually see them?

Tags: neuroscience, vision, hallucinations, pseudoscience

I have found that seeing "auras" is [used](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/migraine-with-aura/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20352077) for diagnosis of some neuropathologies. However, I wasn't able to find evidence that some people truly see what is colloqially known as [auras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aura_(paranormal)). Is there any evidence that some neurological conditions can trigger seeing lights of different colors around people based on that person's personality as perceived by the observer or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

**Simply answer to the question:** Yes, but without real evidence and sole *speculative*.

From neuroscience perspective it may be possible that those people can `self-induce` waves in brain to sole affect visual cortex, so it may be possible and plausible but didn't encountered any research to back those claims.

According to publication [Migraine with visual aura associated with thicker visual cortex](https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/141/3/776/4817415) that aura (symptom) does have an impact on the brain, *increased cortical thickness of visual and somatosensory areas in patients with migraine with aura*, more precise due the increased neural density on those parts on the brain, brain does change and not all time in a good direction, generating more damage.

Most of the people capable of "seeing" aura (paranormal, spiritual or alternative medicine) had an "episode" of excessive brain stimulation and can percept energy completely different compared with others (ones reality is others illusion). At the end of the day were said: **Reality is merely an illusion, albeit a very persistent one**.

**Note:** I won’t deny the fact that by this waves to be enhanced power of `visual cortex` can be associated with seeing other objects `energy` fields as are specialized as [Rose aura camera](https://www.google.com/amp/s/nuvomagazine.com/daily-edit/canadas-first-aura-camera/amp), at the end of the day we are `biological machines` and is still a lot of unknown when does come to neuroscience and brain in general, if those brain neurons/synapse does use electrical to work then we can `anecdotal` say that by this waves, humans can get supernatural `powers` by seeing energy fields around. so far most of aura symptoms does precedes and upcoming damage to human brain or lets say “to biological agents” in general.

**More explanation/details from pure Neuroscience perspective**

“**Aura**” referenced in [Migraine with aura](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/migraine-with-aura/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20352077) should be paired with neuroscience/neurology symptoms [An aura is a perceptual disturbance experienced by some with epilepsy or migraine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aura_(symptom)) with additional info from Mayo Clinic [What is AURA](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/what-is-aura)  and **NOT** with [paranormal, spiritual or alternative medicine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aura_(paranormal))

**To add some more details to give more “weight” to aura as symptom:**  A set of symptoms or sensations, such as flashing lights or zigzag lines, which typically precede migraine headache, seizure, or other neurological events affecting visual cortex of the brain (is complicated and still unsolved phenomenon) also called focal seizures/partial seizures or simple auras and is due the a wave in brain (electrical or chemical). [A richer view of aura](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-02863-8) from nature is a very good read if u do look for more details.